# Running test from RubyMine gives 'cannot load such file'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I have a test which runs as expected from the command line with:

`bundle exec rake test TEST=test/my_test.rb`

However, when I run the test from RubyMine I get:

`require': cannot load such file -- my_test_helper_gem/test_helper (LoadError)`

When I cmd+click on the require statement in my_test, RubyMine opens the expected source code. Any suggestions of how to resolve this? Possibly it works for the command line due to some magic related to `rake`?