# Rubymine debug mode test framework quit unexpectedly - cannot load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubymine

While debugging rspec unit tests from Rubymine I'm getting this error:

```
Test framework quit unexpectedly

`load': cannot load such file -- NDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL.rb (LoadError)
```

When I run tests in `Run` mode everything works fine. How can I fix this?

I've looked at below problems but they are not similar to mine:

- [RubyMine Unit tests - Test Framework quit unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570266/rubymine-unit-tests-test-framework-quit-unexpectedly)
- [Running test from RubyMine gives 'cannot load such file'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002746/running-test-from-rubymine-gives-cannot-load-such-file)

#### StackTrace:

```
Testing started at 11:30 ...
/bin/bash -c "/Users/vaibhav/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.3.4 do bundle exec /Users/vaibhav/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/bin/ruby /Users/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.0.beta7/bin/rdebug-ide --key-value --disable-int-handler --evaluation-timeout 10 --evaluation-control --time-limit 100 --memory-limit 0 --rubymine-protocol-extensions --port 59453 --host 0.0.0.0 --dispatcher-port 59454 -- /Users/vaibhav/codebase/orca/bin/rspec /Users/vaibhav/codebase/orca/spec/lib/job_processors/onboarding_processor_spec.rb --require teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter --format Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter --example \"JobProcessors::OnboardingProcessor#perform Onboarding should run the job and return true and promote onboarding and service to stable state\" --no-color"
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.7.0.beta7, debase 0.2.3.beta5, file filtering is supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:59453
Running via Spring preloader in process 60174
/Users/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load': cannot load such file -- NDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL.rb (LoadError)
    from /Users/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/vaibhav/.spring.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:263:in `block in invoke_after_fork_callbacks'
    from /Users/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:262:in `each'
    from /Users/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:262:in `invoke_after_fork_callbacks'
    from /Users/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:198:in `block in serve'
    from /Users/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `fork'
    from /Users/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `serve'
    from /Users/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
    from /Users/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
    from /Users/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
    from /Users/vaibhav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/vaibhav/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/vaibhav/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: could you please check how it goes in the released RubyMine 2019.1.1 RC?

Comment: From where can I get that specific version?

Comment: From here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/RUBYDEV/Early+Access+Program

Comment: It worked with EAP version. It has some patch/update for spring configurations. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who has faced the same issue: it is a known problem (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-24021) that is fixed starting from RubyMine 2019.1.1 RC.